# Passing value from props to react Redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've built a login page in react with protected routes. So far if I try to navigate to a protected route without being logged in, I'm redirected to the login page - and the page I originally requested is stored in props.location.state.from.pathname.

On the login page, I'm trying to conditionally render a different react Redirect component depending on whether there is a value in props.location.state.from.pathname.

```
const renderRedirect = () => {
if (redirect) {
  if (props.location.state) {
    console.log('returning via props.location.state');
    return <Redirect to={props.location.state.from.pathname} />;
  } else {
    console.log('returning via /');
    return <Redirect to={'/'} />;
  }
}


};
```

I can see that the page is running the code within the if(props.location.state) as I get the console.log. But the return is not firing to the location specified in the props. I just remain on the login page.

The login process is running successfully - I get the expected cookies sent to me and if I change the URL slug manually I can access the protected routes which the redirect should be sending me to.

The second part of this function also works fine - if props.location.state is undefined then I get the expected console.log and I'm redirected to / after successful login.

Is it something to do with the 'to' parameter of Redirect requiring a string?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd add `console.log(props.location.state.from.pathname)` to make sure it's actually in there.

Comment: @ChrisG yep put that in and I get /account, /staff etc etc in the logs

Comment: Have you checked whether it is redirecting and then immediately redirecting back?

Comment: @NealBurns I'm pretty sure it's not. I've added a `useEffect(() => {console.log('rendered account page')}, []);` to the top of my component for that page and nothing is getting shown in logs. But as soon as I've logged in with that value in props I can manually navigate there by changing the url

Comment: It might be getting redirected before even rendering the component.